# Reinstall Ubuntu tracker

Tags: uninstall, gui, filemanager, tracker

The tracker had high CPU usage on Ubuntu20 Desktop, so I used `sudo apt remove tracker` to uninstall it. However, the GUI went wrong: some logos in app menu disappear, and there's no options to open and process files in GUI.(File manager disappeared either.)

I tried to use `sudo apt-get install tracker` to reinstall tracker, but it didn't work.

How can I fix it???

Thank you!

Comment: Problem solved for me.  I referred to https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html  This blog shows a list of packages removed when uninstall tracker. Just use apt install to install them back.

Comment: In addition, it seems after uninstall and reinstall, problem of high CPU usage of tracker disappeared. =_=!